# python code not executing input requests or running

Tags: python, input

I am trying to teach myself python and it has been going pretty well up until I tried to incorporate input requests. My code is below and it won't run and I'm not getting any errors; can anyone help me? Not sure if this matters but I am trying to run it on python 2.7.

```
alphabetdef = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',    'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

shift = range(26)

def getmessage():
    x = raw_input("Enter the message you want to encrypt: ")
    return x

def getshift():
    while True:    
        shift = raw_input("Enter the number of place shifts you would like: ")
        if shift == int(shift):
            return shift

def mssg(x, y):
    for letter in x:
        if letter in alphabetdef:
            alpha2 = ord(letter) + shift
            secret_message = ""
    if alpha2 in range(0, len(alphabetdef)):
        finalmessage = chr(alphabetdef)
        secret_message += finalmessage

    return secret_message
```

Comment: Fix your indentation first. Also, looks like you are just defining functions, not calling them.

Comment: you defined `getmessage()` but didn't call it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Your last return statement is not shifted over correctly.  Also the 'if' statement
two lines up also need indentation.  Finally, you don't have any code that runs
outside the functions.  That's why you are not getting any output.

Comment: I have just fixed the indentation - how does it look now?